# Variables in Erlang

Tags: erlang

If I am not wrong, in erlang variables are to bind only once.

Like:

```
C = cat.
```

But take this as an example:

```
1> FallVelocity = fun(Distance) -> math:sqrt(2 * 9.8 * Distance) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.111823515>
```

And I can do:

```
3> FallVelocity(20).
19.79898987322333
4> FallVelocity(200).
62.609903369994115
5> FallVelocity(2000).
197.9898987322333
```

Why call a function many times over the course of a program. Doesn’t that mean the same variable will be bound many times?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what do you mean. Which variable is being bound many times in your example? function parameter?

Comment: @miushock I meant to FallVelocity, which returns different values.

Comment: Then Chiron answered it perfectly. Please aware not just variables, function literals need a name too. FallVelocity in this case represent some code to be executed, which remain unchanged.

Comment: @miushock Thank you for adding more info! Erlang is a bit different for me! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FallVelocity** refers to a function. Then you are calling **FallVelocity** a couple of times with different parameters. And of course, each different invocation of **FallVelocity** will yield a different result.

The result of each invocation of **FallVelocity** isn't assigned to **FallVelocity** var. The purpose of **FallVelocity** is to refer to a function, not to the result of the invocation of that function.

What you **can't** do is the following:

```
3> Hoohaa = FallVelocity(20). %% This is ok
   19.79898987322333

4> Hoohaa = FallVelocity(200). %% Nope, it will fail
```

Line #4 will fails because *Hoohaa* Variable is already bounded to 19.79898987322333 (thanks to Patterns matching in Erlang).

Comment: I have a feeling that OP might meant the parameter (Distance) being bound to different values each call.

Comment: @miushock The original intention isn't clear but I think he/she thinks  that since the last line of fun is returning a value, that value is going to be assigned to FallVelocity variable.

Comment: That's where I felt ambiguous too. OP might need to aware that one concept of functional programming is not to alter program state in each function call

Answer (score 4):

In the book *"Introducing Erlang" by Simon St. Laurent* there is a special section that speaks to your question:

> **Functions and Variable Scope**
>
> Erlang lets you bind a variable only once, but you might call a
>   function many times over the course of a program. Doesn’t that mean
>   the same variable will be bound many times? Yes, it will be bound many
>   times but always in separate contexts. Erlang doesn’t consider
>   multiple calls to the same function to be the same thing. It starts
>   with a fresh set of unassigned variables every time you call that
>   function.
>
> Similarly, Erlang doesn’t worry if you use the same variable name in
>   different functions or function clauses. They aren’t going to be
>   called in the same context at the same time, so there isn’t a
>   collision.
>
> The place you need to avoid re-assigning values to an already bound
>   variable is within a given path through a given function. As long as
>   you don’t try to reuse a variable in a given context, you shouldn’t
>   have to worry.

*- Introducing Erlang, Chapter 2 - Functions and Modules, p.18*

Answer (score 1):

Rather than say that each variables are only bound once, it would be more precise to say that each each instance of a variable is only bound once. Each time the `FallVelocity` function is called, this creates an instance of the `Distance` variable, and this instance is bound to the value passed as a parameter in the call to `FallVelocity`.

In Erlang, a given instance of a variable receives a value at the point when it is created, and there is no concept of assigning it a different value afterwards.

Most other languages have the same concept of instances of variables. When you call a function in an imperative language, this creates new instances of its local variables, and these instances disappear when the function returns. The difference between Erlang (and other functional languages) and imperative languages is that an instance of a variable in Erlang designates a value, whereas an instance of a variable in an imperative language designates a storage location, which itself contains a value that can change over time.

As for `FallVelocity`, there is only one instance of it. The value of `FallVelocity` is a function (it is not the result of the function; the value returned by the function, i.e. the result of the function, is not given a name in your snippet). If you call this function multiple times, the code of the function is executed each time — and it's still the same function that's executed.